# Ansible configuration file

Tags: ansible

I have my `ansible.cfg` file in `/etc/ansible/` as well as `/apps/ansible/`.
We have made all the required setup in `/apps/ansible/`. Now, I have created new user and have all the ssh keys setup for the client nodes. But, when I switch to the user and execute `ansible --version`, its getting the configuration from `/etc/ansible/`. How do I ensure that the configuration is picked up from `/apps/ansible`?

```
[ansible@Server ~]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.4.2.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, May 31 2018, 09:41:32) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]
[ansible@Server ~]$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a user to use /apps/ansible/ansible.cfg you can either

1. Link ~/.ansible.cfg (in the home directory) to /apps/ansible/ansible.cfg, or
2. Set ANSIBLE_CONFIG (environment variable)  to /apps/ansible/ansible.cfg

Refer to [details.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file)

Comment: Option 3: `cd` to `/apps/ansible`